# Java Streaming Objects via HTTP: some Best Practises for Exception Handling?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, exception, stream

For some larger data we use HTTP streaming of objects in our Java-/Spring-Boot-Application. For that we need to bypass Spring MVC a bit like this:

```
@GetMapping("/report")
public void generateReport(HttpServletResponse response) throws TransformEntryException {

    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.json");
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/stream+json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    Long count = reportService.findReportData()
            .map(entry -> transfromEntry(entry))
            .map(entry -> om.writeValueAsBytes(entry))
            .peek(entry -> out.write(entry))
            .count();

    LOGGER.info("Generated Report with {} entries.", count);
}
```

(...I know this code won't compile - just for illustration purposes...)

This works great so far - except if something goes wrong: let's say after streaming 12 entries successfully, the 13th entry will trigger an TransformEntryException during transfromEntry().

The stream will stop here. And the client gets indicated that his download finished successfully - while it was only part of the file.

We can log this server side and also attach some warning or even stacktrace to the downloaded file, but the client gets indicated that his download finished successfully - while it was only part of or even corrupt file.

I know that the HTTP status code gets sent with the header - which is already out. Is there any other way to indicate to the client a failed download?

("Client" most cases means some Webbrowser)

Comment: Do note, that since java 11 (I believe), the `peek` is not guaranteed to run when terminal operation is `count()` if stream size is known already - i.e. if the stream has `SIZED` trait.

Comment: Would your `report.json` file contain sequence of object and not at array then, like this: `{...} {...} {...}`? Since you don't seem to write neither `[` nor `]`. What if you did, and client counted the braces? If there's no closing brace, then the file is not complete.

Comment: According to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming all are possible. However for backward compatibility we actually format as proper JSON array [ {...}, {...}, ... ], using some custom collector - but this is kind of complicated code as we need to stay non-blocking. That's why I stripped it away in the code example.

Comment: But the collector still doesn't finish properly, and since client got `[` but no `]`, they can say their download is broken even if you returned them `200 OK`.

Comment: True, but the Webbrowser won't check the downloaded file for `]`...

Comment: Stepping back a little, have you tried just catching the exception, and setting error status on `response` in catching block? It sounds like the first thing anyone will try, but still?